# Consume secured WSO2 web service "Sign and encrypt - X509 Authentication" with SOAPUI

Tags: soapui, wso2, x509

I'm trying to invoke a WSO2 secured proxy service using the "Sign and encrypt - X509 Authentication" scenario.
I've configured a X509 certificate in WSO2 and everything looks fine for WSO2.

On the client side, I'm using SOAPUI 4.5.1.
I've followed several tutorials to get it work without success...
The laste error I'm getting is this one:
General security error (WSSecurityEngine: Callback supplied no password for: null); nested exception is: 
    javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException

Don't know which password is null.... 
Is there something to develop on the server side?
The Soap request contains the timestamp, signature and the encryption part and it seems to be OK.

Any idea?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: I've looked at the WSO2 ESB samples, but not much help..

Comment: please attach the full error logs and request message too. What are the exact configurations you did at the wso2 server end ? Did you pic the scenario 5 and what keystores did you select ?

Answer (score 0):

This blog post [1] would help you to configure security scenario with SoapUI. Did u get this error in server side? Both server and client side need to resolve the password of keystore and private key to complete encryption and signing process. If you use UI security wizard in WSO2 side,  Most probably those password must be configured by default and you do not want to do any additional configurations.  Therefore may be issue with SoapUI side.

[1] http://blog.thilinamb.com/2011/02/invoking-secured-web-service-with.html